# JQuery Click function is only running the last IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onclick

I have written a basic jQuery function which is designed to open and close the bottom menu ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8w913tp/)). However it seems to only be firing the last `if` statement in the `click` function.

I have created a variable called `openNclose` which is defaulted to `false` as the menu isn't open. Once opened, it should change to `true` and fire off the closing `if` statement, however this isn't working.

```
 $(menuContainer).click(function() {

        if (openNclose == true) {    
            $(menuContainer).css("height", "50px");
            $(menuOpen).css("bottom", "50px");
            openNclose = false;
        }

        if (openNclose == false) {
            $(menuContainer).css("height", "200px"); 
            $(menuOpen).css("bottom", "200px");
            openNclose = true;
        }

        console.log(openNclose);
    });
```

Comment: Use `if(openNclose == true){...} else {...}`

Comment: When you set it to true and then click again, the first if gets evaluated and sets it to false. Then the next if statement sees that it's false and sets it back to true.

Comment: Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/p8w913tp/2/).

Comment: Wicked, thanks that seemed to simple haha, thank you all for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `if` statement, where you set `openNclose = false`, and you follow that with another `if` statement, checking if `openNclose == false`. That means your code is going to satisfy both `if` statements.

Change it to an `else if`, or even just an `else`:

```
$(menuContainer).click(function() {

    if (openNclose == true) {    
        $(menuContainer).css("height", "50px");
        $(menuOpen).css("bottom", "50px");
        openNclose = false;      // setting openNclose to false here
    } else {                     // this will only be hit if openNclose == false
        $(menuContainer).css("height", "200px"); 
        $(menuOpen).css("bottom", "200px");
        openNclose = true;
    }

    console.log(openNclose);
});
```